# State of the art on Extrinsic and Intrinsic Motivation in Other Animals Than Humans?

Tags: motivation, animal-cognition, animal

Most definitions and theories about [intrinsic and extrinsic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation#Intrinsic_and_extrinsic) motivations (that I could find) are about human animals, and there are [some interesting debates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overjustification_effect#Controversy) about the conversion between those (but again, only in the context of humans). Yet, the reward systems at the origins of such behaviors, such as the  [Striatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Striatum), are common to all vertebrates (and one can observe both intrinsically and extrinsically motivated behaviors in other animals than humans (e.g. a dog playing "for the fun of it" vs a dog performing a trick for a reward)).

It has become common to use computer activities to both enrich the life and study the sensory and cognitive abilities of other animal than humans (e.g. [Egelkamp et al.](https://doi.org/10.1002/zoo.21458)'s review on zoo-based cognitive research using touchscreens, and my own contribution studying [Monk Parakeet parrots' discrimination abilities using a touchscreen game](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.00734)), and as the frontier between intrinsic and extrinsic motivation is blurred for humans learning through computer activities  (e.g. [Hariri et al.](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12909-018-1249-4) studied the conversion of extrinsic into intrinsic motivation in relation to computer based testing in humans), it seems that the same phenomenon could occur with other animals than humans.

What is the state of the art

- about intrinsic and extrinsic motivations in other animals than humans, and in particular
- about the active and passive conversion processes between them (where *active* refers to ones voluntarily activated by human guardians, and *passive* to ones occurring without any voluntary action from human guardians)?

I could not find any references about such topics, and would like to start designing some experiments exploring in this direction. But I am relatively new to the field (from Theoretical Computer Science to Animal Computer Interaction to Psychology to Neuro-Psychology, I am far from my field of expertise) and I am afraid that I might be missing references, maybe because of using an inadequate terminology. Any help welcome, even harsh criticisms (and suggestions of more adequate SE canals)!